# Backbone JS and Rails 3.2 Error in Production Server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, backbone.js

I got an issue here. I'm working on an app built with Rails and Backbone. In my development environment, everything's run well, but when I deployed it to the production server, this error showed in my firebug :

> TypeError: this._reset is not a function
>     ...;return a.success=function(d,e,f){ba.add?"add":"reset",c&&c(b,...

Could anyone help me on this?

**Revision 1**
I've precompiled the assets and this is my Gemfile :

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '3.2.0'

# Bundle edge Rails instead:
# gem 'rails', :git => 'git://github.com/rails/rails.git'

gem 'mysql2'
gem 'devise', '1.5.3'
gem 'friendly_id'
gem 'pry'
gem "paperclip", "~> 2.5.0"
gem "kaminari"
#gem "ckeditor", "3.7.0.rc3"
gem "tinymce-rails"
gem "puma"
gem "tlsmail"
gem "rails-erd"
gem "juggernaut"
gem "thin"

#gem 'execjs'
#gem 'therubyracer'

# Gems used only for assets and not required
# in production environments by default.
group :assets do
  gem 'sass-rails',   '~> 3.2.3'
  gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 3.2.1'

  # See https://github.com/sstephenson/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
  # gem 'therubyracer'

  gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.0.3'
end

gem 'jquery-rails'
```

Anyway, I got this new fact. I tried run the app in production mode in my local machine and it ran well, but not in my server. Is there anything that I forgot to install in my server?

Comment: can you post your Gemfile, also.. have you precompile your asset in production environment?

Comment: Yep, rake assets:precompile could help.

Comment: I've performed the rake assets:precompile. I also had edited the question and found other issue. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you install backbone manually.

I recommend using something like backbone-rails gem to help integrating rails and backbone gracefully. Something like https://github.com/codebrew/backbone-rails (there are also other gem around, but codebrew implementation is one of the most popular).

This is to ensure consistent dependency across machines.

Don't forget to read about asset pipeline, most of my problem with js and rails in production comes from my lack of understanding regarding rails 3 asset pipeline: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html

And if you're serious about integrating backbone and rails, https://learn.thoughtbot.com/products/1-backbone-js-on-rails is an indispensable resource (at US$ 49)

**EDITED:**
This is my typical Gemfile when creating backbone.js & rails app:

```
group :assets do
  gem 'haml-rails', '~> 0.3.4'
  gem 'sass-rails', '~> 3.2.5'
  gem 'bootstrap-sass', '~> 2.0.3.1'
  gem 'compass', '~> 0.12.1'
  gem 'compass-rails', '~> 1.0.2'

  gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 3.2.2'
  gem 'jquery-rails', '~> 2.0.2'
  gem 'jquery-ui-rails', '~> 1.1.0'
  gem 'handlebars_assets', '~> 0.4.4'

  gem 'rails-backbone', '~> 0.7.2'

  # javascript
  gem 'haml_coffee_assets', '~> 1.2.0'
  gem 'execjs', '~> 1.4.0'
  gem 'therubyracer', '~> 0.10.1'
  gem 'uglifier', '~> 1.2.4'
  gem 'yajl-ruby', '~> 1.1.0'
end
```

Comment: hmm... well most likely the culprit is your server then.. don't forget to make sure that your server use the same ruby version.. and identical version of gem by specifying the version verbosely using '~> 1.0.0' or '= 1.0.0'